# Using __constant qualifer in OpenCL kernels

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, opencl

I am having trouble using the *__constant* qualifier in my OpenCL kernels. My platform is Snow Leopard.

I have tried initializing a CL read-only memory object on the GPU, copying my constant array from host into it. Then I set the kernel argument just as with *__global* memory arguments, but this does not work as it should but I see no error or warnings. I have also tried using the data directly in the clSetKernelArg function as with *float* and *int* types, it works neither.

Do I make any mistakes or is there something wrong with Apple's implementation? I would like to see any working examples how this is done, both OpenCL (gpu) and host code.

Answer (score 4):

I doubt there is something so fundamental wrong with Apple's implementation. I used the following [OpenCL Hello World Example](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/OpenCL_Hello_World_Example/index.html) application to get my head around the basics.

In this example I replaced the `__global float* input` with `__constant float* input` and it worked fine. You also need to make sure your buffer is `CL_MEM_READ_ONLY`, using something like  `clCreateBuffer(context,  CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,  sizeof(float) * count, NULL, NULL)`.

From reading the spec, I think __constant => __global + CL_MEM_READ_ONLY.

I'm running Snow Leopard on MBP 15".

Answer (score 3):

There are some bugs with the way Apple's OpenCL compiler handles `__constant` variables on the GPU.  If the compiler log says something like

```
OpenCL Build Error : Compiler build log:
Error while compiling the ptx module: CLH_ERROR_NO_BINARY_FOR_GPU
PTX Info log: 
PTX Error log:
```

then I had the same error as you, and filed a bug on it.  The folks at Apple marked it as a duplicate (of rdar://7217974 apparently) so I assume it's a known problem and they're working on it.

Answer (score 3):

"From reading the spec, I think __constant => __global + CL_MEM_READ_ONLY."

Not really, when you specify _constant instead of __global, you are saying to your device to save this data in a different portion of memory. In some devices, its true that can be the same, but others couldn't be. On NVIDIA cards, for instance, you've only 64kb of _constant memory and loads of mb for __global. The advantage on __constants is that in NVIDIA devices, it is cached:)

You can query your device: (example of my device query)

CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE:       128 MByte

CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE:      255 MByte

CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE:       16 KByte

CL_DEVICE_MAX_CONSTANT_BUFFER_SIZE: 64 KByte

Comment: **The __constant or constant address space name is used to describe variables allocated in
global memory and which are accessed inside a kernel(s) as read-only variables** . These from the OpenCL Spec. I think the constant memory on OpenCL is different with CUDA. I mean that access __constant  not faster than __global.