# OpenCL: Difference between __constant memory and const __global memory

Tags: opencl, constants

I would like to understand what the difference is when I create a buffer with read-only property and use it with `__constant` address space qualifier in the kernel or use it with `const __global` address space qualifier.

What I have already found those are not really answers for my question but they contain some useful information:

- https://community.khronos.org/t/constant-vs-const-global
- [Is the access performance of __constant memory as same as __global memory on OpenCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153443/is-the-access-performance-of-constant-memory-as-same-as-global-memory-on-ope?rq=1)
- [Using __constant qualifer in OpenCL kernels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576862/using-constant-qualifer-in-opencl-kernels)

If I understand well the allocation in GPU's memory happens at clCreateBuffer function call. So what I do not understand is how the compiler decides the buffer is in the constant memory (which has a 64 KB limit) or in the global memory. (I know that in most of the cases the constant memory is a part of the global memory space.) If it depends on the address qualifier that means the 64 KB limit can be ignored using `const __global`.

Is there any difference in performance between `__constant` and `const __global`? The __global memory may be cached so both of them is read-only and (may be) cached.
(Source: 3.3 Memory Model/Global memory section and Figure 3.3;  http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.x-latest.pdf#page=24)

Comment: My guess is it depends on the OpenCL implementation and/or the hardware architecture.

Answer (score 3):

Based on my experiences there is no conceptual difference between the two, they both imply that the data that is pointed to is read only. The difference is only then apparent depending on the implementation used by the vendor.

For example on nvidia GPUs memory marked with __constant is cached (the size of the cache  is 8KB per multiprocessor I believe for all current devices). One thing to note is accesses to this cache are serialized if different work items access different addresses and thus I've found it most useful for passing structs of parameters that are constant within a work group.  If you look at the section on constant memory in the CUDA programming guide you'll get a better idea as to how this works. Memory marked const __global is not cached I believe, it simply tells the compiler to throw an error if you try to change pointed to values.

I'm not sure whether AMD do a similar kind of caching on their hardware

Hope that helps

Comment: Are you sure the size of the cache is 64KB? I think the whole __constant memory space is 64KB. (See CL_DEVICE_MAX_CONSTANT_BUFFER_SIZE)

Comment: You are indeed correct I was mistaken. Whilst the total size is 64KB the cache is 8KB per multiproccessor. I've updated my answer to correct this.

Answer (score 2):

For Intel's (formerly Altera's) SDK for OpenCL on FPGAs, constant memory is loaded into on-chip constant cache which is shared by all work-groups. The size of this cache is 16 KB by default, but can be changed if you add the `-const-cache-bytes=<N>` (with `<N>` being the the constant cache size in bytes) flag to your `aoc` command. Their [Best Practices Guide](https://www.altera.com/en_US/pdfs/literature/hb/opencl-sdk/aocl-best-practices-guide.pdf) page 138 also mentions the following:

> Unlike global memory accesses that have extra hardware for tolerating long memory
>   latencies, the constant cache suffers large performance penalties for cache misses. If
>   the 
>   `__constant`
>    arguments in your OpenCL kernel code cannot fit in the cache, you
>   might achieve better performance with 
>   `__global const`
>    arguments instead.

Comment: this seems to be my experience in some situations: `__global const` gives me up to 2% better performance in some situations (if the buffer is huge, mostly) on intel chips, but this difference is so tiny, it may be a coincidence / statistical error.

Answer (score 0):

For AMD's OpenCL implementation, see the explanation here:
https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/ROCm/issues/203

Basically, *constant* has the effect of an implicit *restrict*.
Thus *constant int *p* is mostly equivalent to *const global int * restrict p*.

Answer (score -1):

`constant` is similar to `immutable` in [D](https://dlang.org/spec/const3.html). It means the value won't change during the whole kernel execution (all work-items).
`const` on the other hand only means that the pointed memory will not be changed through *this* `const` pointer, but still can change through aliased non-`const` pointers.

`constant` implies `const` (if no-one can change the data, neither can you).

`constant` is a huge optimization opportunity for the compiler. It can emit code to dereference the pointer just once per work-item and keep the value in a register (GPUs have lots of registers!), or even share the dereferenced value between different work-items in a sub-group.

As for how the compiler decides the buffer is in the constant memory, it's simple: if you wrote `constant` in the kernel, it's constant address space. This means the decision is made no earlier than at the `clSetKernelArg` time.